# gt table makes the df to a list when piped direct after wrangling data

Tags: r, gt

Hi I'm trying to learn gt tables, but if I %>% gt() at the end of my code it changes my df to a list.

But if I after my code run df %>% gt() it works.

Why can't I pipe direct to gt()

my data is from the NFLverse package

```
library(nflfastR)
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
```

this changes my df to a list, and don't show the table in viewer

```
pbp_rp <- load_pbp(2023) %>%
  drop_na(yards_gained) %>% 
  filter(rush == 1 | pass == 1, !is.na(yards_gained)) %>%
  select(posteam, yards_gained, week) %>%
  group_by(posteam) %>% 
  summarise(att = sum(!is.na(yards_gained)),
            lost_att = sum(yards_gained <0),
            zero_att = sum(yards_gained == "0"),
            positive_att = sum(yards_gained >0),
            lost_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained<0]),
            yards_0_10 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=0 & yards_gained<10]),
            yards_10_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=10 & yards_gained<20]),
            yards_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=20]),
            positiv_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>0]),
            yards_total = sum(yards_gained),
            lower = min(yards_gained),
            avg = mean(yards_gained),
            upper =max(yards_gained)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt()
```

if I instead do this it works and the viewer shows my table

```
pbp_rp <- load_pbp(2023) %>%
  drop_na(yards_gained) %>% 
  filter(rush == 1 | pass == 1, !is.na(yards_gained)) %>%
  select(posteam, yards_gained, week) %>%
  group_by(posteam) %>% 
  summarise(att = sum(!is.na(yards_gained)),
            lost_att = sum(yards_gained <0),
            zero_att = sum(yards_gained == "0"),
            positive_att = sum(yards_gained >0),
            lost_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained<0]),
            yards_0_10 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=0 & yards_gained<10]),
            yards_10_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=10 & yards_gained<20]),
            yards_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=20]),
            positiv_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>0]),
            yards_total = sum(yards_gained),
            lower = min(yards_gained),
            avg = mean(yards_gained),
            upper =max(yards_gained)) %>% 
  ungroup()  
pbp_rp %>% gt()
```

Comment: Both variants work as expected for me and produce a gt-table. Try restarting you R session and/or updating your packages.

Comment: A `gt` table or object is basically a `list`. In your first code you store this `list` as a variable or object `pbp_rp`. To display or print the table you have to run `pbp_rp`. In your second code you store the original dataframe as `pbp_rp`. And when you do `pbp_rp %>% gt()` the data frame gets converted to a `list` too but gets printed at once.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I understand why now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the table is not shown in the Viewer tab when running the first of your two code chunks is that you're missing a line specifying that you want to print the table. It's a bit like running `x <- 8` and expecting R to print the number 8, if that makes sense.

If you want to store the `gt_tbl` object in a variable named `pbp_rp`(which is what you're doing in the first code chunk) and then print the table, you simply have to add a line containing `pbp_rp` like so:

```
pbp_rp <- load_pbp(2023) %>%
  drop_na(yards_gained) %>% 
  filter(rush == 1 | pass == 1, !is.na(yards_gained)) %>%
  select(posteam, yards_gained, week) %>%
  group_by(posteam) %>% 
  summarise(att = sum(!is.na(yards_gained)),
            lost_att = sum(yards_gained <0),
            zero_att = sum(yards_gained == "0"),
            positive_att = sum(yards_gained >0),
            lost_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained<0]),
            yards_0_10 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=0 & yards_gained<10]),
            yards_10_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=10 & yards_gained<20]),
            yards_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=20]),
            positiv_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>0]),
            yards_total = sum(yards_gained),
            lower = min(yards_gained),
            avg = mean(yards_gained),
            upper =max(yards_gained)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt()

# Display table:
pbp_rp
```

But unless you need the `gt_tbl` object for something in multiple parts of your code, there's nothing wrong in using `pbp_rp %>% gt()` like you have done in your second code chunk.

However, if you just want to display the table once without saving it for later use, you could also just do this:

```
load_pbp(2023) %>%
  drop_na(yards_gained) %>% 
  filter(rush == 1 | pass == 1, !is.na(yards_gained)) %>%
  select(posteam, yards_gained, week) %>%
  group_by(posteam) %>% 
  summarise(att = sum(!is.na(yards_gained)),
            lost_att = sum(yards_gained <0),
            zero_att = sum(yards_gained == "0"),
            positive_att = sum(yards_gained >0),
            lost_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained<0]),
            yards_0_10 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=0 & yards_gained<10]),
            yards_10_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=10 & yards_gained<20]),
            yards_20 = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>=20]),
            positiv_yards = sum(yards_gained [yards_gained>0]),
            yards_total = sum(yards_gained),
            lower = min(yards_gained),
            avg = mean(yards_gained),
            upper =max(yards_gained)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes so much sense

Comment: @JackieNielsen No worries! I see now that someone had already helped you in the comments, but please consider accepting my answer (unless stefan posts an answer themselves, but that seems unlikely at this point) :) 
Here are some posts about stackoverflow answer etiquette that might be useful: 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks. this was my first post so I didn't know how to accept answer.